# Oracle SEQUENCE.NEXT VAL Table or view does not exist

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am using a sequence for a table. I have created a new sequence. If I run the sequence in SQL Developer its working fine. If I use that from the java application I am getting table or view does not exist" exception. I am able to connect to other sequences from the same database connection. Just after creating this I am getting this exception.

> SEQUENCE.NEXT VAL Table or view does not exist

SEQUENCE SQL:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "OWNER"."SEQ_ID"  
    MINVALUE 1 
    MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 
    INCREMENT BY 1 
    START WITH 250 
    CACHE 20 
    NOORDER NOCYCLE;
```

Comment: Check your connection - are you targeting the right server?  The correct database?

Comment: @Siyual Yes. All other queries are running fine in the application. Actually the sequence used to exist previously.I have edited that and created as a new sequence from then its giving that error.Not really sure where its going worng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check grants on sequence.you have access to that object.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This helped. I have added grants which worked out. Thanks a lot @ashish